# Very Basic Beginner SQL script

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I need help writing some very basic SQL code. I do not need an eleborate code, the very basics of SQL. I will write my database first, then have the question under.

Okay so I have the four following tables:

- Division(**did**, dname, managerID)
- Employee(**empid**, name, salary, *did*)
- Project(**pid**, pname, budget, *did*)
- Workon(***pid***, ***empid***, hours)

The text is bold is the primary key and the text in italic is the foreign key. The Workon table connects both the employee and project tables.

Here are my questions:

1. List the name of divisions that have/sponsor project(s) employee 'chen'  works on.

   This is what I have...

   ```
   select pname, d.dname
   from project p, division d
   where pid in
        (select pid
         from employee e, workon w
         where e.empid=w.empid and lower (name) 'Chen')
   ```

   Now I know this is not completely right because I think I have to take it from the Workon table, but I am unsure how to.
2. List the name of the employee that has the lowest salary in his division and list the total number of projects this employee is work  on (use correlated subquery).

   This is what I have

   ```
   select name, did, min(salary) as "lowest salary"
   from employee
   group by name, did
   order by did
   ```

   and I also have this code..

   ```
   select did, min(salary)
   from employee
   group by did
   order by did
   ```

   I am confused because the first code is not only giving me the lowest salary of the division. (If you look at the second code I wrote it shows the average.)
3. List the name of employee who do more projects than his/her divisional colleagues (correlated subquery).

   I have...

   ```
   select pname
   from project p, workon w
   where p.pid= w.pid
   group by pname
   having count (empid) >2
   ```

   I have a feeling this shouldn't be more than 2. It should be more than the colleague, but I can not figure out how to write that.
4. List the name of project that some employee(s) who is/are working on it make less than divisional average salary.

   ```
   select dname 
   from division d, employee e
   where d.did= e.did 
   group by dname
   having avg(salary)>(select avg(salary) from employee)
   ```

   I do not think this is right either, but I know I am almost there

Comment: This is a "Question and Answer" site. Note that both of those are singular. This is not a "Many Questions and Answers Site", or a "Several Broad Questions site" , or a "Multiple questions that serve as a tutorial when answered" site. One question per post, so that one answer can be selected as being correct or most helpful. If you're not sure how the site works, revisit the [tour] (which you agreed to having done when you created your account here) and spend some time in the [help] pages.

Comment: I hope you are not asking about your homework.

Comment: What DBMS are you using, `Oracle` or `MySQL`?

Comment: If you are being taught the `from project p, division d` implicit join notation, please tell your teacher (politely) that SQL-92 introduced a better way of writing queries with explicit joins and please can they teach you 21st Century SQL instead of 20th Century SQL (the new notation has been standardized for over twenty years!).  Note that you need joining conditions in a WHERE clause with the implicit join notation.

Answer (score 0):

Search for TDQD on SO to see how I go about Test-Driven Query Design.  You can test each step of the query as it is built up, and if something goes wrong with a step, take appropriate corrective action to make the query correct.

I'll tackle the first of your queries:

- List the names of divisions that sponsor projects that employee 'chen' works on.

Given your attempted query, I am going to assume that your DBMS supports a function `LOWER(x)` that case-converts all the letters in its argument to lower-case, leaving any non-letters alone.

Taking this one step at a time, we might come up with:

#### 1. Employee ID for employee 'chen'

```
SELECT EmpID
  FROM Employee
 WHERE LOWER(Name) = 'chen'
```

#### 2. Project IDs of projects that employee 'chen' works on

```
SELECT W.PID
  FROM WorkOn   AS W
  JOIN Employee AS E
    ON E.EmpID = W.EmpID
 WHERE LOWER(E.Name) = 'chen'
```

#### 3. Division IDs of divisions sponsoring projects that employee 'chen' works on

```
SELECT P.DID
  FROM Project  AS P
  JOIN WorkOn   AS W ON W.PID = P.PID
  JOIN Employee AS E ON E.EmpID = W.EmpID
 WHERE LOWER(E.Name) = 'chen'
```

#### 4. Names of divisions sponsoring projects that employee 'chen' works on

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.Dname
  FROM Division AS D
  JOIN Project  AS P ON P.DID = D.DID
  JOIN WorkOn   AS W ON W.PID = P.PID
  JOIN Employee AS E ON E.EmpID = W.EmpID
 WHERE LOWER(E.Name) = 'chen'
```

The DISTINCT removes any repeats if 'chen' works on several projects sponsored by the same division.

You need to apply a similar technique to the other queries in your question.  I'm not sure that you need any correlated subqueries.  You will probably need 'subqueries in the FROM clause', but you shouldn't need correlated subqueries — IMO, of course.  If I spent long enough on it, I could probably come up with a correlated subquery, but such queries are unlikely to perform as well as straight-forward queries and will probably be a lot harder to read (and write).  You'll need to assess whether your tutor will accept correct answers that do not use correlated subqueries (but that do produce the correct answer).